# Angularfir2 display price ascending using orderByChild

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

In my ionic application I am using angularfir2 v5 and now I have a situation in which I need to display products `price` ascending/descending order using category id in `orderByChild` field. Below in my DB structure

```
products:
  aaa:
    price: 10
    cat_id: 1
  fff:
    price: 9
    cat_id: 1
  ccc:
    price: 11
    cat_id: 1
  ddd:
    price: 10
    cat_id: 2
```

and this is my code that I am trying to achieve above.

```
this.productRef = this.db.list(`/product`, ref => ref.orderByChild('cat_id').equalTo(1));
this.product = this.productRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

this give me price in random order and I want to get price in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it in client-side, doing:

```
load() {
  this.productRef = this.db.list('/product', ref => { 
      return ref.orderByChild('cat_id').equalTo(1)
  }).valueChanges();

  this.productRef.subscribe((products) => {
    this.sortedProducts = products.sort((a,b) => a.price <= b.price ? -1 : 1);
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes this works fine. Now I have another question that is there any way that I can get the last and first element before going to view page. Mean want to get lowest and higher price.

Comment: Yes. For example, you can call `load()` function in `ngOnInit()` and get `let first = this.sortedProducts[0]` and `let last = this.sortedProducts[this.sortedProducts[0].length -1]`